# Given $x_1^3+x_2^3+...+x_9^3=0$. Find the maximum value of $S=x_1+x_2+...+ x_9$.

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given 9 real numbers $x_1, x_2, ... , x_9\in [-1,1]$ such that $x_1^3+x_2^3+...+x_9^3=0$. Find the maximum value of $S=x_1+x_2+...+ x_9$.

I have tried ordering the numbers from smallest to largest and then dividing the set of integers $\{x_1, x_2, ... , x_9  \}$ into two subsets of only negative numbers and only positive numbers. In particular,

$S_1 =\{ x_1, x_2,..., x_j \}$ and $S_2 =\{ x_{j+1}, x_{j+2},..., x_9 \}$ such that all the elements in $S_1$ are negative and all the elements in $S_2$ are positive.

From there, letting $-(x_1^3+ x_2^3+... x_j^3)= x_{j+1}^3+ x_{j+2}^3+... x_9^3=P$ and evaluating some inequalities, I got:

$maxS=\sqrt[3]{(9-j)^2P}-[\left\lfloor P \right\rfloor+\sqrt[3]{P-\left\lfloor P \right\rfloor}]$

This answer was impossibly complicated and I can't seem to find the maximum of S with respect to $j$ and $P$.

Is there a better solution to this? If not, how do I find the maximum of S?

Comment: Maximum seems to be when one of them is $-1$ and all the rest $\frac12$.  A simple proof (without knowing this maximum apriori) seems difficult though.

Comment: Check: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1511338p8974134

Answer (score 8):

Notice that for $-1\leq x \leq 1$ there exists a number $t$ such that $\cos(t)=x$. We have:
$$
4\cos^3(t)-3\cos(t) = \cos(3t) \geq -1\\
\Rightarrow 4x^3 - 3x \geq -1\\
\Rightarrow x\leq \frac{4x^3+1}{3}$$
Or you can prove by showing that $4x^3-3x+1\geq0$. Applying this to our sum, we obtain:
$$\sum_{i = 1}^9 {x_i} \leq \frac{4}{3}\sum_{i = 1}^9 {x_i^3} + \frac{9}{3} = 3$$
The equal sign happens when $x_i \in \{1/2, -1\}$ and the constraint $\sum_{i = 1}^9 {x_i^3} = 0$ is satisfied. It is possible by letting:
$$x_1=x_2=...=x_8=\frac{1}{2},x_9 = -1$$

Comment: How do we know that it's maximum ? Why only considered $x\in[-1,1]$ ?

Comment: @An_Elephant the range of $x$ was given in the question. It is maximum because the value of the sum is always less than or equal to that.

Comment: This approach works for $n=9$ terms (or its multiples) only, as coincidentally the solution turns the inequality into an equality for these cases.  For other $n$, e.g. $n=3,4,5,...$, it fails.

Comment: @ioveri Oops sorry , I didn't saw the range.